# How would you remove all emojis from string?

Tags: replace, string, emojis

Basically what the title says, I'm looking for the best way to remove all emojis from a string.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Unicode and Emacs have differing definitions of what constitutes an emoji, and then there are eg emoji ZWJ sequences to worry about.

Comment: @rpluim I'm scraping a web using `url-retrieve-synchronously`, getting the content using `buffer-substring`, formatting strings with emojis messes up functions that format strings (I guess that's where ZWJ comes to play, although I'm not familiar with that), is there a way to remove all unicode characters that display emojis and only emojis? I've tried something like `(setf my-string (replace-regexp-in-string "[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}\x{2700}-\x{27BF}\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}\x{24C2}\x{1F1E0}-\x{1F1FF}]" "" my-string))` but it also removes other normal chatacters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For emoji which are single characters, and which Emacs displays as emojis, you can do something like:

```
(defun strip-emoji (str)
  "Remove characters which are part of the `emoji' script from STR."
  (cl-remove-if (lambda (c)
                  (equal (aref char-script-table c) 'emoji))
                str))

(strip-emoji "This:  or that ") => "This:  or that "
```